# Why would identical copies of the same C loop in the same program take significantly but consistently different times to execute?

Tags: c, loops, assembly, intel, memory-alignment

I hope that I have reduced my question to a simple and reproducible test case.  The source (which is [here](https://gist.github.com/nkurz/0fbb2f2332a3142c9d15)) contains 10 copies of an identical simple loop.  Each loop is of the form:

```
#define COUNT (1000 * 1000 * 1000)
volatile uint64_t counter = 0;

void loopN(void) {
  for (int j = COUNT; j != 0; j--) {
    uint64_t val = counter;
    val = val + 1;
    counter = val;
  }
  return;
}
```

The 'volatile' of the variable is important, as it forces the value to read and written from memory on each iteration.  Each loop is aligned to 64 bytes using '-falign-loops=64' and produces identical assembly except for the relative offset to the global:

```
   400880:       48 8b 15 c1 07 20 00    mov    0x2007c1(%rip),%rdx  # 601048 <counter>
   400887:       48 83 c2 01             add    $0x1,%rdx
   40088b:       83 e8 01                sub    $0x1,%eax
   40088e:       48 89 15 b3 07 20 00    mov    %rdx,0x2007b3(%rip)  # 601048 <counter>
   400895:       75 e9                   jne    400880 <loop8+0x20>
```

I'm running Linux 3.11 on an Intel Haswell i7-4470.   I'm compiling the program with GCC 4.8.1 and the command line:

```
 gcc -std=gnu99 -O3 -falign-loops=64 -Wall -Wextra same-function.c -o same-function
```

I'm also using **attribute**((noinline)) within the source to make the assembly clearer, but this is not necessary to observe the issue.  I find the fastest and slowest functions with a shell loop:

```
for n in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; 
do echo same-function ${n}:; 
/usr/bin/time -f "%e seconds" same-function ${n}; 
/usr/bin/time -f "%e seconds" same-function ${n}; 
/usr/bin/time -f "%e seconds" same-function ${n}; 
done
```

It produces results which are consistent to about 1% from run to run, with the exact numbers of the fastest and slowest functions varying depending on the exact binary layout:

```
same-function 0:
2.08 seconds
2.04 seconds
2.06 seconds
same-function 1:
2.12 seconds
2.12 seconds
2.12 seconds
same-function 2:
2.10 seconds
2.14 seconds
2.11 seconds
same-function 3:
2.04 seconds
2.04 seconds
2.05 seconds
same-function 4:
2.05 seconds
2.00 seconds
2.03 seconds
same-function 5:
2.07 seconds
2.07 seconds
1.98 seconds
same-function 6:
1.83 seconds
1.83 seconds
1.83 seconds
same-function 7:
1.95 seconds
1.98 seconds
1.95 seconds
same-function 8:
1.86 seconds
1.88 seconds
1.86 seconds
same-function 9:
2.04 seconds
2.04 seconds
2.02 seconds
```

In this case, we see that that loop2() is one of the slowest to execute and loop6() is one of the fastest, with a difference just over 10%. We reconfirm this by testing just these two cases repeatedly with a different method:

```
nate@haswell$ N=2; for i in {1..10}; do perf stat same-function $N 2>&1 | grep GHz; done
     7,180,104,866 cycles                    #    3.391 GHz
     7,169,930,711 cycles                    #    3.391 GHz
     7,150,190,394 cycles                    #    3.391 GHz
     7,188,959,096 cycles                    #    3.391 GHz
     7,177,272,608 cycles                    #    3.391 GHz
     7,093,246,955 cycles                    #    3.391 GHz
     7,210,636,865 cycles                    #    3.391 GHz
     7,239,838,211 cycles                    #    3.391 GHz
     7,172,716,779 cycles                    #    3.391 GHz
     7,223,252,964 cycles                    #    3.391 GHz

nate@haswell$ N=6; for i in {1..10}; do perf stat same-function $N 2>&1 | grep GHz; done
     6,234,770,361 cycles                    #    3.391 GHz
     6,199,096,296 cycles                    #    3.391 GHz
     6,213,348,126 cycles                    #    3.391 GHz
     6,217,971,263 cycles                    #    3.391 GHz
     6,224,779,686 cycles                    #    3.391 GHz
     6,194,117,897 cycles                    #    3.391 GHz
     6,225,259,274 cycles                    #    3.391 GHz
     6,244,391,509 cycles                    #    3.391 GHz
     6,189,972,381 cycles                    #    3.391 GHz
     6,205,556,306 cycles                    #    3.391 GHz
```

Considering this confirmed, we re-read every word in every Intel architectural manual ever written, sift through every page on the entire web that mentions the words 'computer' or 'programming', and meditate in isolation on a mountaintop for 6 years.   Failing to achieve any sort of enlightenment, we come down to civilization, shave our beard, take a bath, and ask the experts of StackOverflow:

What can possibly be happening here?

**Edit:** With Benjamin's help (see his answer below) I've come up with an even more [succinct test case](https://gist.github.com/nkurz/1ecb46486746c4e078b3).  It's a standalone 20 lines of assembly.  Changing from using SUB to SBB causes a 15% difference in performance even though the result remains the same and the same number of instructions are executed.  Explanations?  I think I'm getting closer to one.

```
; Minimal example, see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/26266953/3766665
; To build (Linux):
;   nasm -felf64 func.asm
;   ld func.o
; Then run:
;   perf stat -r10 ./a.out
; On Haswell and Sandy Bridge, observed runtime varies 
; ~15% depending on whether sub or sbb is used in the loop
section .text
global _start
_start:
  push qword 0h       ; put counter variable on stack
  jmp loop            ; jump to function
align 64              ; function alignment.
loop:
  mov rcx, 1000000000
align 64              ; loop alignment.
l:
  mov rax, [rsp]
  add rax, 1h
  mov [rsp], rax
; sbb rcx, 1h         ; which is faster: sbb or sub?
  sub rcx, 1h         ; switch, time it, and find out
  jne l               ; (rot13 spoiler: foo vf snfgre ol 15%)
fin:                  ; If that was too easy, explain why.
  mov eax, 60
  xor edi, edi        ; End of program. Exit with code 0
  syscall
```

Comment: How are you accounting for background processes interrupting your program? (I'm not very familiar with Linux but on Windows this is a huge issue when trying to time simple but long-running code.) When the thread goes to sleep, it spends an unknown time interval not running when the timer is still - likely - ticking.

Comment: This does not appear to be an issue with processor contention.  That might account for the variation in times among runs for the same N, but it does not account for the consistent, statistically-significant difference in runtimes for different N.

Comment: What is the address alignment for, say, `loop6` and `loop1` - are they both 32 byte aligned ? Do they have the same overall alignment ?

Comment: @xxbbcc: The consistency of the difference between the loop routines makes me doubt that this is an issue, but I've tried to account for it by turning off hyperthreading and pinning the process to a specific core.  Additionally, 'perf stat' tells me the number of 'context switches', which appears to be consistent and small.  The effect remains even if I reduce the number of loop iterations so that it runs without interruption.

Comment: FWIW I ran your code on a MacBook Pro with a Haswell CPU using Apple's clang compiler and the timings were consistent for all values of N.

Comment: @NathanKurz Have you also disabled turbo boost?  You'll want to ensure that the CPU isn't dynamically scaling the frequency.  Also, did you try changing the loop execution order?

Comment: As a further data point, all loops run the same speed on my AMD FX8350 under linux.

Comment: @PaulR: In the case that I gave timings for, aall of the loopN functions are 64B aligned.  0000000000400640 <loop0>, 00000000004006a0 <loop1>, 00000000004006e0 <loop2>, 0000000000400720 <loop3>, 0000000000400760 <loop4>, 00000000004007a0 <loop5>, 00000000004007e0 <loop6>, 0000000000400820 <loop7>, 0000000000400860 <loop8>, 00000000004008a0 <loop9>.  While trying to narrow this down, I tried adjusting this independently of the actual loop alignment, but it was the loop alignment that seemed to matter.

Comment: @MooseBoys: TurboBoost was disabled with "echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/boost" and Frequency Scaling with "for num in 0 1 2 3; do echo performance >  /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu${num}/cpufreq/scaling_governor; done".  I confirmed with i7z that this took effect.  I have not tried changing the loop order per se, but since that would have the effect of changing just a single character in the name of the function, I feel confident that the speed is associated with the position rather than the name.  But I'll explore this route if nothing else is promising.

Comment: On another system I checked the assembly was slightly different. it used `%rax` where yours has `%rdx`; and `%edx` where yours has `%eax`

Comment: @PaulR: When I run here with clang 3.4, I get a smaller but distinct difference.  clang doesn't accept the '-falign-loops=64' flag, so this might be causing the difference.   Perhaps there is another way to specify this?  Intel's icc 14.0.3 demonstrates no difference for me, which I believe is related to the fact that it is using a single 'incl [mem]' rather than separate 'mov, inc, mov' instructions.

Comment: @NathanKurz Are you aware that your loops seem to be only 32-byte aligned?  For example in loop1, 0x6A0 / 64 = 26.5.

Comment: @MooseBoys:  Oops, you are correct, and my hex division is terrible.  But when I tested function alignment, I was doing it in assembly with .p2align, and think I got it right there.  I tried aligning both functions and loops from 2^1 to 2^12 (and surprisingly found effect out to 2^10).   Adding '-falign-functions=64' gives me 64B alignment for the functions, and changes which functions are fast and slow, but does not change the magnitude of the difference.

Comment: If you're executing the process 10 times (i.e., the program runs the loop once every time), then the answer is *cache state*. If you're repeating the loop within the same process (i.e., a single program executes the loop 10 times), then the answer is *cache state* **and** *branch prediction*.

Comment: @barakmanos:  I don't think this is an issue, since it wouldn't explain the consistent differences between functions.  Separately, I've measured the number of L1 cache misses and branch mispredictions with 'perf' and 'likwid' and found no difference.  But for completeness, the timings I show are for three executions of the program.  Each invocation calls the chosen function once.  The function runs the loop 1 billion times.

Comment: @Jester:  Thanks for trying to confirm there.  I get similar results on Sandy Bridge as Haswell, but haven't tried any AMD processors.  It may be worth trying different values for '-falign-loops', as sometimes (by chance?) the timings come out the same for all 10 cases.   On Sandy Bridge, for example, 64B alignment has less magnitude of effect than 8B.

Comment: As another data point, timings for all functions are consistent on my i5-2450m Sandy Bridge machine.

Comment: @rohit89:  Odd, I tested on a Sandy Bridge E5-1620 and found the effect to be about the same.  I did have to change the alignment a bit before the effect was as large.  Could you try out a few different values for '-falign-loops', or or omit it, or compare across a couple alignments?  I saw low effect at 64B loop alignment, medium effect at 8B and 32B, and strong at 16B.

Comment: Try pinning the program to a specific core

Comment: @James:  I've done so with likwid-perfctr, and also likwid-pin combined with perf, and have seen no difference in effect.  I have not yet tried isolating a CPU at bootup with isolcpus, but the consistency of the results makes me think this is not a major issue.

Comment: Those results are pretty consistent, why do you have a problem with those numbers, why would you expect them to be more equal than 1%?  Sounds like a case of managing expectations...

Comment: @dwelch: Maybe I wasn't clear?  The 1% difference is the consistency between runs of the same function.  I presume I could get it down further if I wanted to isolate the process better.  It's the unexplained 12% difference (7 billion cycles vs 6 billion cycles, the bottom quoted panel starting N=2 and N=6) between functions with identical instructions that confuses me.

Comment: @dwelch:  I've done a fair amount of optimization to this degree, and this is the first on Haswell where I haven't been able to understand this level of difference.   Pipelining is complex, but very consistent.   There is no disk involved. I'm pretty sure there isn't even an RAM involved, although I'd need to remeasure this.  There is no difference significant in cache misses, TLB misses or branch mispredictions.  There is a difference in the number cycles for the legacy instruction decoder vs the decoded instruction buffer (IDQ.ALL_MITE_CYCLES_ANY_UOPS vs IDQ.ALL_DSB_CYCLES_ANY_UOPS).

Comment: @dwelch: The numbers for RESOURCE_STALLS.RS (reservation station) correspond to the slowdown, but I think this is a symptom rather than a cause.  I think Sections 3.6.5.2 and 3.4.2.6  of the Intel Optimization manual are relevant here, but I can't figure out exactly how: http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf

Comment: you are running billions of loops with no ram involved on an operating system, please explain that one...I dont think we are ever going to converge on our opinions of what is going on here.

Comment: Sure, it's an executable.  But it doesn't affect the behaviour of the inner loop.   I can increase the number of iterations of the inner loop to as many as needed to reduce the level of noise.  Choosing 1 billion iterations seems to contribute about 1% error, which I considered acceptable for trying to show (rather than exactly measure) a ~10% effect.  I've separately measured more exactly with less common tools like 'likwid' for just the inner loop, and confirmed that the numbers are mostly accurate.

Comment: @dwelch:  "please explain that one".  The inner loop accesses a single cacheline in L1, and runs completely from the L1 instruction cache.  If I change to measuring only the inner loop using the 'likwid' marker API, and if I measure a slightly modified function (adding a superfluous xchg %edx, %edx slow down the issue of the next load) I measure runtimes that are consistent to the first 6 figures of both cycles and instructions.   I also see ~10,000 L1D misses.  While I overstated to say "no RAM", I believe the active core doesn't have enough loads from RAM to have any significant influence.

Comment: @NathanKurz Yup. I was able to reproduce the behaviour when I changed the alignment to 8 and 16. 32 showed no measurable difference. One thing I noticed was that every odd numbered or even numbered loop took the same time. Could this be some sort of icache issue?

Comment: My current belief is that this is a "wicked problem" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wicked_problem).  Per Intel (http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf) "if a load is scheduled too soon after the store it depends on or if the generation of the data to be stored is delayed, there can be a significant penalty".  Separately, something causes the Decoded Instruction Buffer to fail and fall back to the legacy instruction decoder.  Wickedly, using the slower pathway delays the load, resulting in faster overall operation.

Answer (score 9):

Looking at the full perf stat output, you will see that it is not the number of instructions that varies but the number of stalled cycles.

Looking at the disassembly, I have found two things:

1. The offset to the counter variable varies between the functions. Making counter local to each function did not make the behaviour go away, though.
2. The functions are not placed on 64 byte boundaries, so they may cover a different amount of cache lines. Compiling with -falign-functions=64 did make the differences go away almost completely.

Doing the test with the aforementioned changes on my machine then yields:

`for f in $( seq 7); do perf stat -e cycles -r3 ./same-function $f 2>&1; done|grep cycles
     6,070,933,420      cycles                     ( +-  0.11% )
     6,052,771,142      cycles                     ( +-  0.06% )
     6,099,676,333      cycles                     ( +-  0.07% )
     6,092,962,697      cycles                     ( +-  0.16% )
     6,151,861,993      cycles                     ( +-  0.69% )
     6,074,323,033      cycles                     ( +-  0.36% )
     6,174,434,653      cycles                     ( +-  0.65% )`

I don't know more about the nature of the stalls you found, though.

**EDIT:**
I have made counter a volatile member in each function, tested different compilations on my I7-3537U and found `-falign-loops=64' actually to be the slowest:

```
$ gcc  -std=gnu99 -O3 -Wall -Wextra same-function.c -o same-function
$ gcc -falign-loops=64 -std=gnu99 -O3 -Wall -Wextra same-function.c -o same-function-l64
$ gcc -falign-functions=64 -std=gnu99 -O3 -Wall -Wextra same-function.c -o same-function-f64
$ for prog in same-function{,-l64,-f64}; do echo $prog; for f in $(seq 7); do perf stat -e cycles -r10 ./$prog $f 2>&1; done|grep cycl; done
same-function
     6,079,966,292      cycles                     ( +-  0.19% )
     7,419,053,569      cycles                     ( +-  0.07% )
     6,136,061,105      cycles                     ( +-  0.27% )
     7,282,434,896      cycles                     ( +-  0.74% )
     6,104,866,406      cycles                     ( +-  0.16% )
     7,342,985,942      cycles                     ( +-  0.52% )
     6,208,373,040      cycles                     ( +-  0.50% )
same-function-l64
     7,336,838,175      cycles                     ( +-  0.46% )
     7,358,913,923      cycles                     ( +-  0.52% )
     7,412,570,515      cycles                     ( +-  0.38% )
     7,435,048,756      cycles                     ( +-  0.10% )
     7,404,834,458      cycles                     ( +-  0.34% )
     7,291,095,582      cycles                     ( +-  0.99% )
     7,312,052,598      cycles                     ( +-  0.95% )
same-function-f64
     6,103,059,996      cycles                     ( +-  0.12% )
     6,116,601,533      cycles                     ( +-  0.29% )
     6,120,841,824      cycles                     ( +-  0.18% )
     6,114,278,098      cycles                     ( +-  0.09% )
     6,105,938,586      cycles                     ( +-  0.14% )
     6,101,672,717      cycles                     ( +-  0.19% )
     6,121,339,944      cycles                     ( +-  0.11% )
```

More details on align-loops vs align-functions:

```
$ for prog in same-function{-l64,-f64}; do sudo perf stat -d -r10 ./$prog 0; done

 Performance counter stats for './same-function-l64 0' (10 runs):

       2396.608194      task-clock:HG (msec)      #    1.001 CPUs utilized            ( +-  0.64% )
                56      context-switches:HG       #    0.024 K/sec                    ( +-  5.51% )
                 1      cpu-migrations:HG         #    0.000 K/sec                    ( +- 74.78% )
                46      page-faults:HG            #    0.019 K/sec                    ( +-  0.63% )
     7,331,450,530      cycles:HG                 #    3.059 GHz                      ( +-  0.51% ) [85.68%]
     5,332,248,218      stalled-cycles-frontend:HG #   72.73% frontend cycles idle     ( +-  0.71% ) [71.42%]
   <not supported>      stalled-cycles-backend:HG
     5,000,800,933      instructions:HG           #    0.68  insns per cycle
                                                  #    1.07  stalled cycles per insn  ( +-  0.04% ) [85.73%]
     1,000,446,303      branches:HG               #  417.443 M/sec                    ( +-  0.04% ) [85.75%]
             8,461      branch-misses:HG          #    0.00% of all branches          ( +-  6.05% ) [85.76%]
   <not supported>      L1-dcache-loads:HG
            45,593      L1-dcache-load-misses:HG  #    0.00% of all L1-dcache hits    ( +-  3.61% ) [85.77%]
             6,148      LLC-loads:HG              #    0.003 M/sec                    ( +-  8.80% ) [71.36%]
   <not supported>      LLC-load-misses:HG

       2.394456699 seconds time elapsed                                          ( +-  0.64% )


 Performance counter stats for './same-function-f64 0' (10 runs):

       1998.936383      task-clock:HG (msec)      #    1.001 CPUs utilized            ( +-  0.61% )
                60      context-switches:HG       #    0.030 K/sec                    ( +- 17.77% )
                 1      cpu-migrations:HG         #    0.001 K/sec                    ( +- 47.86% )
                46      page-faults:HG            #    0.023 K/sec                    ( +-  0.68% )
     6,107,877,836      cycles:HG                 #    3.056 GHz                      ( +-  0.34% ) [85.63%]
     4,112,602,649      stalled-cycles-frontend:HG #   67.33% frontend cycles idle     ( +-  0.52% ) [71.41%]
   <not supported>      stalled-cycles-backend:HG
     5,000,910,172      instructions:HG           #    0.82  insns per cycle
                                                  #    0.82  stalled cycles per insn  ( +-  0.01% ) [85.72%]
     1,000,423,026      branches:HG               #  500.478 M/sec                    ( +-  0.02% ) [85.77%]
            10,660      branch-misses:HG          #    0.00% of all branches          ( +- 13.23% ) [85.80%]
   <not supported>      L1-dcache-loads:HG
            47,492      L1-dcache-load-misses:HG  #    0.00% of all L1-dcache hits    ( +- 14.82% ) [85.80%]
            11,719      LLC-loads:HG              #    0.006 M/sec                    ( +- 42.44% ) [71.28%]
   <not supported>      LLC-load-misses:HG

       1.997319759 seconds time elapsed                                          ( +-  0.62% )
```

Both executables have a very low instructions/cycle count, probably due to the minimalistic nature of the loop and the memory pressure that it is inflicting, but I have no idea on why one is worse than the other.

I have also tried something along the lines of

```
$ for prog in same-function{-l64,-f64}; do sudo perf stat -eL1-{d,i}cache-load-misses,L1-dcache-store-misses,cs,cycles,instructions -r10 ./$prog 0; done
```

and

```
$ sudo perf record -F25000 -e'{cycles:pp,stalled-cycles-frontend}' ./same-function-l64 0
[ perf record: Woken up 28 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 6.771 MB perf.data (~295841 samples) ]
$ sudo perf report --group -Sloop0 -n --show-total-period --stdio
$ sudo perf annotate --group -sloop0  --stdio
```

But without any success on finding the culprit. Still, I felt it might be helpful to jot it down here for you anyway...

**Edit 2:**
Here is my patch to same-function.c:

```
$ git diff -u -U0
diff --git a/same-function.c b/same-function.c
index f78449e..78a5772 100644
--- a/same-function.c
+++ b/same-function.c
@@ -20 +20 @@ done
-volatile uint64_t counter = 0;
+//volatile uint64_t counter = 0;
@@ -22,0 +23 @@ COMPILER_NO_INLINE void loop0(void) {
+volatile uint64_t counter = 0;
@@ -31,0 +33 @@ COMPILER_NO_INLINE void loop1(void) {
+volatile uint64_t counter = 0;
@@ -40,0 +43 @@ COMPILER_NO_INLINE void loop2(void) {
+volatile uint64_t counter = 0;
@@ -49,0 +53 @@ COMPILER_NO_INLINE void loop3(void) {
+volatile uint64_t counter = 0;
@@ -58,0 +63 @@ COMPILER_NO_INLINE void loop4(void) {
+volatile uint64_t counter = 0;
@@ -67,0 +73 @@ COMPILER_NO_INLINE void loop5(void) {
+volatile uint64_t counter = 0;
@@ -76,0 +83 @@ COMPILER_NO_INLINE void loop6(void) {
+volatile uint64_t counter = 0;
@@ -85,0 +93 @@ COMPILER_NO_INLINE void loop7(void) {
+volatile uint64_t counter = 0;
@@ -94,0 +103 @@ COMPILER_NO_INLINE void loop8(void) {
+volatile uint64_t counter = 0;
@@ -103,0 +113 @@ COMPILER_NO_INLINE void loop9(void) {
+volatile uint64_t counter = 0;
@@ -135 +145 @@ int main(int argc, char** argv) {
-}
\ No newline at end of file
+}
```

**Edit 3**: Same thing with even more minimal example:

```
; Minimal example, see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/26266953/3766665 
; To build (Linux):
;   nasm -felf64 func.asm
;   ld func.o
; Then run:
;   perf stat -r10 ./a.out
; Runtime varies ~10% depending on whether 
section .text
global _start
_start:
  push qword 0h       ; put counter variable on stack
  jmp loop            ; jump to function
;align 64             ; function alignment. Try commenting this
loop:
  mov rcx, 1000000000
;align 64             ; loop alignment. Try commenting this
l:
  mov rax, [rsp]
  add rax, 1h
  mov [rsp], rax
  sub rcx, 1h
  jne l
fin:                  ; End of program. Exit with code 0
  mov eax, 60
  xor edi, edi
  syscall
```

Same effect here. Interesting.

Cheers,
   Benjamin

Comment: Modern processors are complex non-deterministic beasts.  The one you are testing has L2 and L3 cache, 4 cores, 8 threads, branch prediction and out of order execution.  Stalls come from the myriad of interactions between all these aspects of the CPU. A cache miss, leads to a memory access, leads to a possible thread switch, leads to a flushing of branch prediction, etc.  When you look at the detailed schematic of the CPU its a wonder that the thing even works and gives you consistent answers most of the time.  Can't expect it to time tham all the same as well.

Comment: I touched on this briefly in an early comment.  While the function alignment makes a difference, I think it's just because it affects the address of the loop within.  If I compile with "gcc -std=gnu99 -O3 -falign-functions=64 -falign-loops=64 -Wall -Wextra same-function.c -o same-function", I see numbers from 6,271,509,852 to 7,191,368,933, with a matching degree of precision.  Do you see this as well when you add back -falign-loops=64?  Does it stay constant for when you try different align-loops values?   Your loop and perf command is particularly elegant -- thank you for demonstrating it!

Comment: @Nathan, I took the compilation instructions from the comment on top of same-function.c, failed to note that it did not contain the -falign-loops=64 you have suggested and then checked for alignment with "eu-readelf -s same-function | grep loop" and "objdump -d same-function". I was just wondering that the code wasn't aligned on 64 byte boundaries and if maybe instruction cache misses might be an issue, so I have tried -falign-functions. I will try to answer your other questions in the evening, since I'm away from my machine right now. Cheers!

Comment: @Natan, also I was using a different architecture (sandy bridge), but I could reproduce your initial findings there as well.

Comment: Could you please put the exact source code you used for "gcc  -std=gnu99 -O3 -Wall -Wextra same-function.c -o same-function" example online?   I'd look to look at the assembly and see if there are things to be learned from the exact alignments.  Since the difference between 0 and 1 is very large, it might be possible to reduce the test case down to just those two to make it more focussed.  But often when reducing, it changes the alignment so that the effect goes away.  Thanks for pursuing this.

Comment: Ok, just put it in my answer. Really nothing spectacular. For all three sets of compile flags, I have compiled this code.

Comment: I like your tiny asm example, since it removes a lot of the extraneous things that were distracting people.  I've tweaked it a little to create an even more dramatic example.  I get a 15% difference on both Haswell and Sandy Bridge when I switch from using 'sub' to 'sbb' in the loop.  Even more exciting, I think I can explain why! Please try it out:  https://gist.github.com/nkurz/1ecb46486746c4e078b3

Comment: I was thinking that sbb should be slower, but I have found it to be the other way around. Absolutely no idea, why...

Comment: I think SBB is faster because of a really strange chain of events.  There are still some parts I don't know, but working backward: internally, SUB/JNE can join together to form a single uop.  SBB does not support macro-fusion.   With fusion (SUB/JNE), the loop has 4 uops.  Without (SBB/JNE) it has 5.   Per Intel optimization manual 3.4.2.5, the SBB version gets delivered as 4 uops then 1 uop in two cycles.  The SUB version is delivered in a single cycle. This difference is why we see more front end stall cycles with the SBB version.  But read on, instead of slowing us down, this speeds us up.

Comment: Per Intel Optimization 3.6.5.2, putting a load too soon after a store to the same address "can lead to sizable but non-deterministic delays".  It even specifically mentions volatile variables.  In this case, it appears that "too soon" means "sent to the RAT in the same cycle".  This causes the slowdown.  Symptomatically, we can measure more store and load instructions than we expect being executed, but only the expected number being retired.  I still don't understand the details of which alignment causes which speed, but I presume it must affect the way uops are being issued.  Mindbending.

Comment: Great research on the explanation there. Would this imply slowness for `l: inc qword [rsp];loop l` as well? I have found this code to be the fastest yet. On a sidenote, I am wondering if any of this has practical consequences, because I have trouble imagining such a loop in actual production code.

Comment: I don't know yet how inc with a memory operand works.  I'll try to explore.  But yes, this does have practical use! I've come across this problem a couple times now, and this is the first time I really tried to figure it out.  The latest application is well described here: http://fastcompression.blogspot.com/2014/09/counting-bytes-fast-little-trick-from.html.  Yann was writing a histogram to count the number of occurrences of each byte as in input to a compression algorithm.  But it performed worse as the data got more predictable.  The predictable case ends up behaving a lot like this loop.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I found your analysis there as well. Now I'm going to burn even more time on this by reading up on likwid - thanks for that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A few years ago, I would have told you to check for any difference in the internal state of the CPU when it arrives at any of those loops; as this was known to have a profound effect on the capacity of the Out-of-Order predictions process (or something like that).  For example, the performance of the very same loop  could change by up to something like 15-20% depending on what the CPU was doing just before entering the loop and just the fact of jumping from two different points could be sufficient to change the execution speed.

In your case, it's quite to test.  All you have to do is to change the order of the instructions in the IF block; for example replacing the following:

```
  switch (firstLetter) {
  case '0': loop0(); break;
  case '1': loop1(); break;
  case '2': loop2(); break;
  case '3': loop3(); break;
  case '4': loop4(); break;
  case '5': loop5(); break;
  case '6': loop6(); break;
  case '7': loop7(); break;
  case '8': loop8(); break;
  case '9': loop9(); break;
  default: goto die_usage;
  }
```

with:

```
  switch (firstLetter) {
  case '9': loop9(); break;
  case '8': loop8(); break;
  case '7': loop7(); break;
  case '6': loop6(); break;
  case '5': loop5(); break;
  case '4': loop4(); break;
  case '3': loop3(); break;
  case '2': loop2(); break;
  case '1': loop1(); break;
  case '0': loop0(); break;
  default: goto die_usage;
  }
```

or with any random order.  Of course, you should check the generated assembly code to make sure that the order of the instructions has not been reordered by the compilator.

Also, as your loops are inside individual functions; you should also make sure that these functions are themselves aligned on 64 bytes boundaries.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your answer. If you are suggesting that the location from which the call occurs determines the speed of the function, I don't know what the mechanism for this might be.  But I changed the order to that you proposed, and found that the position of the function within the switch statement does not affect the speed with which it executes.  That is, the speed appears to be a property of the function.  To reconfirm, I also edited the generated assembly to swap the calls to the 'fastest' and 'slowest' functions from the original, and found that they remained such.

Comment: That's was my idea.  A few years ago, the OOO mecanism was very unpredictable.  In your case, another possibility would be the difference in alignment for each function. You could also check to replace the functions with goto statements.

Comment: *You could also check to replace the functions with goto statements.*  I get similar timing differences when I allow the functions to be inlined, which I think should be the same (or more definitive) than switching to a goto.  It changes which 'function' is fast, but doesn't remove the issue.  I didn't do this in the example because I thought that having everything in main() complicated things.